# Dual Monitor support for MDI applications

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, multiple-monitors

I need to implement dual monitor support for my MDI application. Can anybody suggest a good way to do that.

I tried making my selected child forms 'MDIparent' field to 'null' when running in dual monitor mode to bring the child forms out of the MDI window. But if i reassigned the MDIparent, as i need to do it in dual mode also, the child forms events are not firing correctly.

Any suggestion are welcomed.

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what you would like to do in a dual monitor setup?

Comment: @AlvinWong In a dual mode setup i will view some of my MDI child in screen1 and some in screen2. Bcoz i cant view the contents of those in a single monitor. And scrolling is not a good solution too.

Comment: The best solution is not to use MDI completely. You can compare Word and Excel 2010 and you'll see how annoying Excel is on a dual monitor setup.

Comment: @Alvin Wong so u are suggesting that once if i added a child it should remain as MDI child. And if i need to show it in screen2, i need no show it as a normal form from the applications start itself.